# JS Being Reset on Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, reset

I have several animations that run when a portion of the page is in view. For some reason the animation of the percentage bar filling is reset any time another animation is ran resulting in the percentage bar refilling each time. Below is the code for the percentage bar and below that is an example of another animation that is ran when in view. I've narrowed it down to it being the JS causing the issue, hopefully someone can point out whats causing this issue. Any help is appreciated!

Percentage JS:

```
    /* BAR PERCENTAGE */
function isElementVisible($elementToBeChecked)
{
    var TopView = $(window).scrollTop();
    var BotView = TopView + $(window).height();
    var TopElement = $elementToBeChecked.offset().top;
    var BotElement = TopElement + $elementToBeChecked.height();
    return ((BotElement <= BotView) && (TopElement >= TopView));
}

$(window).scroll(function () {
    $( ".bar-percentage" ).each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        isOnView = isElementVisible($(this));
        if(isOnView && !$(this).hasClass('Starting')){
            $(this).addClass('Starting');
            startAnimation($(this));
        }
    });
});



function startAnimation($this) {
 $('.bar-percentage[data-percentage]').each(function () {
  var progress = $(this);
  var percentage = Math.ceil($(this).attr('data-percentage'));
  $({countNum: 0}).animate({countNum: percentage}, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing:'swing',
    step: function() {
      // What todo on every count
    var pct = '';
    if(percentage == 0){
      pct = Math.floor(this.countNum) + '%';
    }else{
      pct = Math.floor(this.countNum+1) + '%';
    }
    progress.text(pct) && progress.siblings().children().css('width',pct);
    }
  });
});
}
```

Other Animation Example:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $( "#about-image-1" ).each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        isOnView = isElementVisible($(this));
        if(isOnView && !$(this).hasClass('fadeIn')){
            $(this).addClass('fadeIn');
            startAnimation($(this));
        }
    });
});
```